# limit information in menu_tree_all_data

Tags: 7

If I am using the menu_tree_all_data command, how can that be modified to just get some data, not all?  in other words I want to get all of the menu items, but not all of the information, eg
updated: "0",
load_functions: null,
to_arg_functions: null,
access_callback: null,
access_arguments: null,
page_callback: null,

which I don't need.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a function to get rid of unwanted elements

```
function removeUnwanted($j)
{
    unset($j['link']['load_functions']);
    unset($j['link']['tab_parent']);
    unset($j['link']['router_path']);
    unset($j['link']['page_callback']);
    unset($j['link']['page_arguments']);
    unset($j['link']['title_callback']);
    unset($j['link']['title_arguments']);
    unset($j['link']['theme_callback']);
    unset($j['link']['theme_arguments']);
    unset($j['link']['access_callback']);
    unset($j['link']['access_arguments']);
    unset($j['link']['tab_root']);
    unset($j['link']['to_arg_functions']);
    unset($j['link']['in_active_trail']);
    unset($j['link']['delivery_callback']);
    unset($j['link']['description']);
    unset($j['link']['localized_options']);
    $j['link']['href'] = drupal_get_path_alias($j['link']['href']);


    foreach ($j['below'] as $key => $r) {

       $j['below'][$key]= removeUnwanted($r);

    }
    return $j;
}
```